# Sort string cumulative date column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe which has `date` column as follows, here `2019Y1-11M` represents data of 2019 from Jan to November, `2019Y1-10M`represents data of 2019 from Jan to October.

How can I sort them by setting `2018Y1-01M` as first and `2019Y1-11M` as last?

```
          date
0   2019Y1-11M
1   2019Y1-10M
2   2019Y1-09M
3   2019Y1-08M
4   2019Y1-07M
5   2019Y1-06M
6   2019Y1-05M
7   2019Y1-04M
8   2019Y1-03M
9   2019Y1-02M
10  2019Y1-01M
11  2018Y1-12M
12  2018Y1-11M
13  2018Y1-10M
14  2018Y1-09M
15  2018Y1-08M
16  2018Y1-07M
17  2018Y1-06M
18  2018Y1-05M
19  2018Y1-04M
20  2018Y1-03M
21  2018Y1-02M
22  2018Y1-01M
```

I think of splitting `2018Y1-01M` into two columns `2018` and `01` then I can do it, just wonder if it's possible without this process. Thanks.

Comment: `df.sort_values('date')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sort_values:

```
>>> df.sort_values(by = 'date')
          date
22  2018Y1-01M
21  2018Y1-02M
20  2018Y1-03M
19  2018Y1-04M
18  2018Y1-05M
17  2018Y1-06M
16  2018Y1-07M
15  2018Y1-08M
14  2018Y1-09M
13  2018Y1-10M
12  2018Y1-11M
11  2018Y1-12M
10  2019Y1-01M
9   2019Y1-02M
8   2019Y1-03M
7   2019Y1-04M
6   2019Y1-05M
5   2019Y1-06M
4   2019Y1-07M
3   2019Y1-08M
2   2019Y1-09M
1   2019Y1-10M
0   2019Y1-11M
```